# Batch file for multiple servers

Tags: file, batch-file, winscp

I created a batch file for deleting files on remote servers and it's working, but I am not able to use it on multiple servers.

For example:

```
cd C:\Program Files\WinSCP
winscp.com /command ^
    "open sftp://test:pwd@server1" ^
    "cd ""/home/test/Desktop/rot & Sec""" ^
    "rm *.txt *.csv *.spn" ^ 
     close

cd C:\Program Files\WinSCP
winscp.com /command ^
    "open sftp://chief:pwd@server2" ^
    "cd ""/home/chief/Desktop/rot & Sec""" ^
    "rm *.txt *.csv *.spn" ^
```

It's not deleting files on `server2`.

Comment: *"It's not deleting files on server2."* - So what does it do? Any error message?

Comment: i want to delete files on 3 remote servers like server1,server2,server3. so i created batch batch file for that but its not working. when i run batch file it delete only server1 file its not going to on server2. for ref. please see above batch file

Comment: The second command must do something. It cannot be just silently skipped. So what do it do currently? If you are not able to describe what does it do, show us a screenshot at least.

Comment: Btw, I assume the `close` line was just omitted from the second command, when posting. Or are you really missing that?

Comment: its not going on second command .its stop after deleting files on server1. no error showing .

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>cd C:\Program Files\WinSCP

C:\Program Files\WinSCP>winscp.com /command     "open sftp://test:pwd@server1"
"cd ""/home/test/Desktop/rot & Security"""     "rm *.txt *.csv *.spn"
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "test".
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] test@server1
/home/test/Desktop/rot & Sec
No file matching '*.txt' found.
No file matching '*.csv' found.
No file matching '*.spn' found.
winscp>